# What is the go-to method for numerical pricing of discrete barriers?

Tags: barrier

There are tons of methods for pricing discrete barrier options in various models?

What is the go-to "classical" method that is most popular?

Hopefully not Monte Carlo (significant accuracy would take ages even with variance reduction since it's path-dependent)....

Answer (score 2):

The ‘classical’ would be PDE based, say Crank Nicolson with Rannacher time marching for local vol based approach, and ADI scheme for Stochastic local vol.